# ADO.NET query returning nothing even if the item available

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am using ADO.NET for querying the SQL Server database. I am trying to get items if present on the table.

My query is executing but returning nothing even if there is.

Here is my code:

```
public List<string> GetRecords(List<string> itemList)
{
    itemList.Add("100");
    string list = string.Join(",", itemList.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)));
    string query = @"SELECT Id FROM Employees WHERE Id In (@list)";

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@list", list);
                sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    employeeList.Add(Convert.ToString(database.Sanitise(sqlDataReader, "Id")));
                }
        }
}
```

There are three items in the list the employee with ID=100 is available in the table but the other two's are not. but still the query returning nothing.

SQL profiler showing me this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
                            Id
                        FROM
                            Employees
                        WHERE
                            Id In (@list)',N'@list nvarchar(29)',@list=N'''50'',''23'',''100'''
```

Comment: Try running your query in SSMS... you'll see you can't pass a comma separated list as a string and use in... without using some form of string_split.

Comment: Parameters are not just string substitutions: they are actual variables. That's the whole point of using them... no possibility at all of evading any kind of escape or sanitization function. Data is data, code is code, and never the twain shall meet. So this is looking for an `IN()` match on **one value** that is everything jumbled together.

Comment: I added the SQL profiler query

Comment: If I run query like that then it give a record for id 100 ```SELECT
 Id
FROM
 Employees
WHERE
 Id In ('50','23','100');```

Comment: Yeah but thats not what you are doing, what you are trying to run is `SELECT Id FROM  Employees WHERE Id In ('''50'',''23'',''100''');` i.e. its a single string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server will not interpret your concatenated list as actual code. It remains data *always*, so it's just one big text string of numbers. That is never going to match a single row.

**Instead, use a Table Valued Parameter.**

First create a table type in your database, I usually keep a few useful ones around.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IdList (Id int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then create a `DataTable` and pass it as a parameter.

```cs
public List<string> GetRecords(List<string> itemList)
{
    var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
        { "Id", typeof(int) },
    } };

    foreach (var id in itemList)
        table.Rows.Add(id);

    const string query = @"
SELECT e.Id
FROM Employees e
WHERE e.Id IN (SELECT l.Id FROM @list l);
";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))  // always create and dispose a new connection
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@list", SqlDbType.Structured) {
            Value = table,
            TypeName = "dbo.IdList",
        });
        connection.Open();
        using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                employeeList.Add((string)sqlDataReader["Id"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note also:

- `using` on all SQL objects.
- Do not cache a connection object. Create when you need it, dispose with `using`.
- I don't know what your `Sanitize` function does, but it probably doesn't work. Sanitizing database values correctly is hard, you should always use parameterization.
- `AddWithValue` is a bad idea. Instead specify the parameter types (and lengths/precision) explicitly.

Comment: Correct, fixed now